# Return data 2 years back same month previous week with date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to extract 2 years ago data with date range greater than 07/01/2019 and 2 years ago same month and week. Need suggestions on date conversion as well

```
select 
    tilr.BusinessUnitID
   ,emph.employeeID
   ,convert(varchar(10), cast(cast(tilr.date_key as varchar(10)) as date), 101) as ConvertDate
   ,tilr.paidhr as 'Paid hr'
from [dbo].[location] tilr
inner join [dbo].[Employee] emph
    on emph.employeeID = tilr.employeeID
    and emph.businessunitid = tilr.BusinessUnitID
    and emph.date_key = tilr.date_key
where 
    
tilr.date_key >= 20190701

and datename(year, convert(varchar(10), cast(cast(tilr.date_key as varchar(10))as date), 101)) 
< DateAdd(YY, -2, GETDATE())
```

Trying to get data for date range >= 07/01/2019 and < 10/23/2019 ( +/- days of same month 2 years ago) for comparison. With above query I'm getting data till end of the year 12/2019 instead of 10/2019.

Sample data

```
BusinessUnitID employeeID  ConvertDate Paid hr  
1234             1          07/01/2019   1.4
2345             2          10/25/2019   3.5
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] i.e. including sample data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Note `SET @STARTDate = convert(varchar(10),'2019/07/01')` should just be `SET @STARTDate = '2019/07/01'` - its already a varchar - no need to convert it. Also you are missing a comma after `tilr.BusinessUnitID`.

Comment: And what the heck is `convert(varchar(10), cast(cast(tilr.[date_key] as varchar(10)) as date), 101)` trying to accomplish? Convert to a varchar, then back to a date, then back to a varchar?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69775268/edit) your question to include the schema of the `Employee` and `Location` tables. The error message suggests that at least one of the `date_key` columns is an `int` data type.

Comment: Still no luck with the recommended changes.

Comment: The recommended changes were never going to fix the problem, they were just cleaning up your query. We need the information requested if you want assistance.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And thats not a [mre]. Build a DB Fiddle for us which reproduces the issue.

Comment: updated my question with new query. please advise!

Comment: You haven't added any of the changes requested. 1) Data as formatted text not image. 2) Sample data for both tables which reproduces the issue ideally a DB Fiddle. 3) The table definitions.

Comment: How do I adjust my date filter to be able to retrieve only till same month same period/week 2 years ago ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need something like the following condition

```sql
tilr.date_key >= DATEADD(month, -2, DATEFROMPARTS( YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2, MONTH(GETDATE()), 1 )) AND
tilr.date_key <  DATEADD(month, 1, DATEFROMPARTS( YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2, MONTH(GETDATE()), 1 ))
```

Note how calculations only use date functions, not conversion to/from `varchar`, and that there are no functions on the actual column value. This means that indexes can be used efficiently.

Comment: Perfect! I've adjusted it to what I wanted to achieve in the range. tilr.[date_key] >= 07/01/2019 and  tilr.[date_key] < DateAdd(Month, 0, DateFromParts( Year(Getdate()) - 2, Month(Getdate()), 1 ))